# from when is the time limit for chargebacks counted?

Tags: mastercard, consumer-protection, chargeback

I've read it's typically 180 days (6 months), but is it usually counted from the date of purchase, or date of delivery (when I could actually check that the good is not fit for purpose?)

Answer (score 1):

This depends on your local laws and your agreement with the bank issuer. It also depends on which network your issuer belongs to - Visa/Mastercard/Diners Club/UnionPay/JCB/American Express/etc etc - there is a bunch. Each has its own rules.

In your case, you found a *Russian* reference, while you're yourself in Armenia. You need to look for local rules. Call your card issuer and ask them.